# PdhExpandWildCardPath returns too many paths

Tags: windows, delphi, performancecounter

I am trying to obtain the CPU utilization of each of the (up to 200) threads in my (Delphi XE) application. To prepare for this I pass to PdhExpandWildCardPath a string `'\Thread(myappname/*)\% Processor Time'`. However (on Win7/64) the buffer returned from this function returns a string for every thread running in the system, in other words it seems to have treated the input as if it were `'\Thread(*/*)\% Processor Time'`.  This was unexpected.  The same happens when I subsequently expand a string to get 'ID Thread'.

Obviously I can filter the resulting strings on the application name and only add the counters I need, but this requires many hundreds of substring scans.  Have I misinterpreted how the wildcards work?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to enumerate the threads in your own process and construct the names that way?

Comment: Why don't you just use GetThreadTimes for each of your threads?

Comment: @David: laziness, I already had the wild-card code done. But thanks, I have now changed my code to enumerate the threads first and it is much quicker. And I still think the wild-card expansion is odd.

Comment: @frogb Ha! I wish I'd put that as an answer rather than a comment now!  ;-)

Comment: @Misha: because the threads come and go and I don't want to have to keep track of them all. If created by a library function I may not have access to a handle to call GetThreadTimes. Otherwise, good idea.

Comment: @Frogb, you always have access to all the threads in your process. You might not know the handle *a priori*, but you can open a handle to any thread with `OpenThread`. To get the IDs of your threads, start with `Thread32First`. But none of this answers your question, which is about wildcard expansion for performance counters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late, but I've hit the same wall, maybe someone else needs it:

Here it is: `'\Thread(myappname*)\% Processor Time'`

Especially useful with ProcessNameFormat set to 2 and ThreadNameFormat set to 2 in `'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PerfProc\Performance'`

For ProcessNameFormat = 2 -> [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd537616(v=vs.100).aspx), same applies for ThreadNameFormat, although I couldn't find any kind of documentation.

Comment: Too late for me, but thanks in advance for when I need it again!